# How to change color of label in Visual Studio's Text Editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, colors, text-editor

I'm using alot of label jump in my C# code. I want change these label color for better seeing. How can I change this? Thank.

```
goto someLabel;
someLabel: // <--------------------- I want change color of this text
```

Comment: *"I'm using alot of label jump in my C# code"*, not saying your doing it wrong, but in 13 years of working with C#, I've only had to use a `goto` once, and I felt really, really dirty doing it. Can I ask why you use so many labels?

Comment: @RonBeyer because I have nested code and want to jump out of it.

Comment: avoiding the `break` dance of nested loops. nice. i see the C++ label can be changed in the options but it doesn't affect C# :( and searching only brings up Form Labels not the code label. how frustrating

Comment: @RadioSpace yes I searched and find nothing.